# Why is ReactJS returning my images as an object?

Tags: html, json, node.js, object, reactjs

I am learning Reactjs by hacking around with the tutorial. I am trying to add Image upload functionality to it but I can't quite figure it out. If I do this:

```
var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
        return(
          <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
            {comment.text}
              <img src={comment.image} alt="none"/>
          </Comment>
        );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

React returns the image as [object Object]. 
I think it has something to do with how ReactJS renders HTML but I cannot figure it out. The comment.image is a url path loaded from a json file. The app can be scrutinized here: https://polar-caverns-82946.herokuapp.com/ and all the code can be seen here: https://github.com/MickyCook/react-app

Comment: can you show us what `this.props.data` looks like?

Comment: Sorry are you asking what the json looks like? https://github.com/MickyCook/react-app/blob/master/comments.json

Answer (score 0):

First, looking at

```
return(
  <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
    {comment.text}
      <img src={comment.image} alt="none"/>
  </Comment>
);
```

You want to return components (Comment) without a closing tag.

```
return (
  <div>
    <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}/>
    <p>{comment.text}</p>
    <img src={comment.image} />
  </div>
)
```

you need to wrap everything in a single element, hence the extra `<div>`. You may also have to dangerously set the image src, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's completely wrapped in a single <Comment> tag, which is valid

Answer (score 0):

in the `Comment` component you have

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
rawMarkup: function() {
  var rawMarkup = marked(this.props.children.toString(), {sanitize: true});
  return { __html: rawMarkup };
},
```

But you can not do that to convert children components to string.

you should use [react-dom](https://github.com/facebook/react)

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
rawMarkup: function() {
  var rawMarkup = marked(ReactDOM.renderToString(this.props.children), {sanitize: true});
  return { __html: rawMarkup };
},
```

Comment: Would using react-dom fix this issue?

Comment: try to print the result like this
`console.log(ReactDOM.renderToString(this.props.children))`

Comment: and if you can wrap the childrens like this `<div> {comment.text}
              <img src={comment.image} alt="none"/></div>` just to make sure react-dom work well

Comment: let me know the result, and hope to help

Comment: I wrapped them like you suggested and do I need to include react-dom differently? I'm using the cdn in the head. Yes the console error is: TypeError: ReactDOM.renderToString is not a function and the other is: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Comment: try to use `ReactDOM.render` or `ReactDOM.renderToStaticMarkup`

Comment: I think i find it !
try to use `React.renderComponentToString(...)` should work

Comment: Alright I'm taking a break to eat I'll try that when I get back and let you know!

Comment: I couldn't get that to work either.. I am probably doing something else wrong.